# JQuery validation on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form that I want to validate using JQuery. 
When the user leaves the form field without entering anything the class of that input changes to show an error by becoming red.

I have created a jsfiddle file 
http://jsfiddle.net/mTCvk/

The problem I am having is that the it will only work on the first text input and the other text inputs will adjust according to the state of the first input.

The JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.text-input').focusout(function () {
       if ($(":text").val().length == 0) {
          $(this).removeClass("text-input").addClass("text-input-error");
       } else {
         $(this).removeClass("text-input-error").addClass("text-input");
      }
  });
});
```

Here is the HTML for the form

```
<form method="post" action="">
<div class="text-input">
    <img src="images/name.png">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="*Name:">
</div>
<div class="text-input">
    <img src="images/mail.png">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="*Email:">
</div>
<div class="text-input">
    <img src="images/pencil.png">
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="*Subject:">
</div>
<div class="text-input">
    <img src="images/phone.png">
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number:">
</div>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="*Message:"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="submit">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a DOM issue.  It needs to check the `:text` child for that specific element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.text-input').focusout(function () {
       if ($(this).find(":text").val().length == 0) {
          $(this).removeClass("text-input").addClass("text-input-error");
       } else {
         $(this).removeClass("text-input-error").addClass("text-input");
      }
  });
});
```

Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mTCvk/2/

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, you have selected the first input type text found : `$(":text").val()`.. You must select the input type type on the .text-input blured :

```
$(":text", $(this)).val()... // First :text, on $(this) parent
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mTCvk/1/

PS : for your class management, don't delete .text-input juste add and remove an other class .text-input-error when you have an error

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(":text").focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("text-input").addClass("text-input-error");
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("text-input-error").addClass("text-input");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code....

```
$('.text-input, .text-input-error').focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).find(':text').val().length == 0) {
        $(this).removeClass("text-input").addClass("text-input-error");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("text-input-error").addClass("text-input");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code to use the .on method, and gave it the event blur. Then we create a variable for the closest text-input class (which would be its parent text-input div). Rather than checking the .length, we just check to see if it is an empty string. You would also need to wrap your textarea in the save text-input div for this to work properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/43e2Q/

```
   $('input, textarea').on('blur', function () {
        var $closestParent = $(this).parent();
       if ($(this).val() == '') {
          $closestParent.removeClass("text-input").addClass("text-input-error");
           console.log('error');
       } else {
          $closestParent.removeClass("text-input-error").addClass("text-input");
           console.log('valid'); 
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks I hadn't got round to setting up the textarea